# How can I reap a zombie process that is not a child of my shell?

Tags: process, zombie-process

I have a server with a ton of zombie processes. Almost a thousand. If possible, I would like to reap these processes because it doesn't seem like the parent (one parent is causing all 1000 zombies) is going to call the wait function. I see bash has a builtin wait function, but when I use it to try to reap one of the zombies, I get the following error.

```
# wait 17517
bash: wait: pid 17517 is not a child of this shell
```

I am root, but that does not seem to make a difference. I have a couple questions

1. Can I reap a zombie process if it is not the child of my shell?
2. If not, is there anything I can do? I am not certain I should kill the parent
3. Should I be worried? It seems the parent has a resource leak and is not garbage collecting or whatever.

Comment: Any solution I can think of would involve stopping the parent and forcing it to execute some system calls (`wait` and `signal(SIGCHLD,SIG_IGN)`). Do you know anything about what the parent is doing when it's not creating children? Is it just listening on a socket?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick Unfortunately, I can't seem to find much about the parent. It is what you would call, a custom application. I would not be able to get more information on my own.

Comment: I'd be more worried about why the zombie processes exist than trying to reap them outside of the parent process.  Are they zombies themselves causing any harm?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons The system seems pretty slow to respond. Probably related. I am just worried that left to themselves, the system will crash. There are no signs of stopping.

Comment: Zombie processes only occupy space in the process table, they wouldn’t explain unresponsiveness.

Comment: @JRFerguson I never said I wanted to kill them

Comment: why does this thread read like a bmovie script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Can I reap a zombie process if it is not the child of my shell?

No, you can't.

> 2. If not, is there anything I can do? I am not certain I should kill the parent

You can try to stop the parent, then restart it with `exec` from a shell that ignores `SIGCHLD`. A parent that ignores `SIGCHLD` won't leave zombies.

> 3. Should I be worried? It seems the parent has a resource leak and is not garbage collecting or whatever.

If the number of zombies increases, eventually you will reach the point where you can't fork new processes.

Comment: with a creative use of gdb, one could make the parent actually call signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) and a few waitpid(-1,NULL,WNOHANG) to plug the leak without restarting it. Of course gdb and production might not go well together.